# How can I set sql variable with character =?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi im trying to set variable like that:

```
declare @password varchar(20)

@password = 'omaBBAA=='
```

but when im using the @password i get different value:

```
select @password
```

I get: omaBBAA

without the '==' at the end of the variable.

how can i fix it??

thaks.

Comment: What SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Also, I don't see you using the `SET` command.

Comment: It may not be the case until your total string length exceeds 20 characters. Can you double check?

Comment: I think some information is missing from the question.

Comment: Its working [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310191/how-can-i-set-sql-variable-with-character). Can't Reproduce. M I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

All works fine  -

```
DECLARE @password1 VARCHAR(20)
SET @password1 = 'omaBBAA==' 
SELECT @password1

-- syntax for 2008 version and higher
DECLARE @password2 VARCHAR(20) = 'omaBBAA==' 
SELECT @password2

DECLARE @password3 VARCHAR(20) 
SELECT @password3 = 'omaBBAA==' 
SELECT @password3
```

Output -

```
--------------------
omaBBAA==
```

Comment: Same here, all works fine. Using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3):

You can do as

```
declare @password varchar(20) = 'omaBBAA=='
```

or

```
declare @password varchar(20)
set @password = 'omaBBAA=='
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
declare @password varchar(20)
set @password = 'omaBBAA==' 

Select @password
```